# Drive-sdk : Changes feed changes().list() How to tell what exactly has changed in a Drive File?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

To be able to detect changes in a user's drive, you can perform [changes().list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list) and have a list of the changes..

But how can you tell what exactly has changed ? if it's a content change , a permission change ? if the file has been shared or trashed or moved to another folder ?!

Comment: I don't think it has that information(though it seems counter intuitive) if you want that info you should setup Push notification on the drive and that returns the change type.

Comment: Even though push notifications provide the change type in the headers, it's still not clear. I have used Push Notifications when wanting to watch changes for files belonging to a specific folder. I ended up creating a channel for each file. Because for instance if I changed a file content, there is no notification sent to the channel surveying the folder. Add to that the expiration problem that I have n't been able to work around !